# Binary retrieval using keywords in Odata service

Tags: 2013, odata

Is it possible to retrieve the binary components based on keyword uri using odata service?

Comment: You can query for a list of components using a given schema and a given keyword - is that what you're asking for?

Comment: Hi Nuno, my requirement is to query all the pdf document which are classified to a keyword. I have to list down all the pdf with hyperlinks to download. My input will be keyword name to get the pdf component.